# Stage optional for other branches but mandatory for master

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Currently we have 4 stages in a GitLab CI pipeline.
All 4 stages are indeed mandatory when someone merges with the master branch.

I can make the last stage "only:master" which would take it out of the pipeline for non-master branch pushes and have it in the pipeline for merges to master.

Is there a way to make the last stage optional/selectable for the non-master branch pushes. There are a small number of instances when we would like to run this stage on regular branches pushes. I envisioned begin able to go to the pipeline of a branch push and be able to click on the last stage to "enable" it for this push and this push only.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up making a template and having 2 steps derive from it, each with different rules. it is working great.

```
.tarball: &tarball
  stage: package
  script:
    - whoami
    - echo $PATH
    - which git-lfs
    - echo "Cloning Common/master"
    - git clone -b master https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/abc/common.git Common
    - echo "Cloning Ansible/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}"
    - git clone -b ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/abc/ansible.git Ansible
    - echo "Excluding the following from tar- ${TAR_EXCLUDES}"
    - tar ${TAR_EXCLUDES} -czf ${TAR_ARCHIVE} Ansible Common 
    - tar -tf ${TAR_ARCHIVE} > manifest.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ${TAR_ARCHIVE}
      - manifest.txt
  tags:
    - shell
 
tarball_master:
    <<: *tarball
    only:
      - master

tarball_other:
    <<: *tarball
    except:
      - master
    when: manual
```